# Adaptive gaussian filter for noise image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, noise

I have one problem that need you help. I have a noise image. Some pixel in the image is very noise, some pixel is not so much noise. So I want to buid a adaptive gaussian filter. That mean the kernel gaussian will depend on the noise status. When pixel is large noise, the gaussian kernel is small. Otherwise, the kernel will large. Could you help me how to calculate the kernel vaule. The input is image noise. Thank you so much

Comment: A **lot** of research has been put forth in figuring out how to make the kernel size adaptive with respect to the noise.  Some people use noise power, and other people take a look at the MSE.  There is no set procedure that will give you the right results.  You're going to compromise when choosing which method you want.

Comment: @rayryeng: Thank sir, could you suggest to me the reference of these methods? Which is more simple and easy to implement?

Comment: Of course!  Check this one out especially: http://asp.eurasipjournals.com/content/2014/1/25 .  The best one I have read so far, and it is a recent publication

Comment: I read this paper. It looks good paper. Do you know which paper that open source code by matlab. Thank you so much

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/wiener2.html).